# Shutdown Windows 7 without installing updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, shutdown

Windows XP provided an option to shutdown the computer without installing any Windows updates. This convenient, time-saving option seems to be missing in Windows 7. Is it possible to shutdown Windows 7 without installing updates?

---

[image: Windows XP]

[image: Windows 7]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`iglvzx`'s answer is the way to go if you want a permanent option in the shutdown menu. This covers the 'once in a while', 'temporary' and 'I'm using Win7 Home so I don't have gpedit' areas.

---

#### Windows 7 Shutdown Dialog

1. Make sure either your desktop or taskbar is in focus. Clicking on the desktop background or on an empty part of the taskbar is enough. Alternatively, the keyboard shortcut `Windows + D` will work.
2. Press `Alt + F4`.
3. You should now have this box:

[[image: Screenshot of Windows 7 update dialog when updates pending]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwird.png)

---

#### Windows 7 Security Screen

1. Press `Ctrl + Alt + Delete` to get to the security screen.
2. Click the arrow next to the shutdown button.
3. You should see this context menu:

[[image: Screenshot of shutdown context menu in Windows 7 security screen]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H2L8.png)

---

#### Turn off automatic updates

This is not temporary, but it is a viable solution for Home users. If you switch your update settings to anything except automatic updates, your shutdown will not install updates. However, if you manually installed the updates, shutdown will still go to the configuring updates screen as usual. Also, be sure to actually install the updates as often as possible.

[[image: Screenshot of Windows 7 update settings screen]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neFH9.png)

Comment: Awesome! Most people I know have the Home Premium version and therefore no gpedit. Very userful!

Comment: `If you switch your update settings to anything except automatic updates, your shutdown will not install updates.` Not true. If you choose the "Download updates but let me choose whether to install them" option, it will never ask you what you want to do on a shutdown. It will automatically install them.

Answer (score 17):

Yes. You can shut down Windows 7 without installing updates by enabling the following **Group Policy** setting:

> Do not adjust default option to 'Install Updates and Shutdown' in Shut Down Windows dialog box

1. **Run** `gpedit.msc`

   [image: Run]
2. Navigate to `Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Updates`

   [image: Windows Updates]
3. **Double-click** the setting, set it to `Enabled`, and click `OK`.

   [image: Enabled]

---

Now, the shut down button in the **Start** menu will default to `Shut down` and include an extra option to `Install updates and shut down`.

[image: Shut down]

Answer (score 10):

In the unlikely event that I want to shut down and *not* install updates, I would use either the run dialog or the command prompt to run:

```
shutdown /s /f /t 10
```

`/s` = shutdown (as opposed to reboot)

`/f` = force running applications to quit

`/t 10` = wait 10 seconds before starting the shutdown (in case you change your mind and want to abort the shutdown)